# Is there a way to check the first array item in a multidimensional array to see if the value has changed?

Tags: javascript

I have a multidimensional array. 2D specifically. The first array is a page number I am storing. The second array is the layer names for the page. My problem is that I am creating a header before each page number. I am trying to loop through and print the header, then 1st page, then the first set of layers. Then second header, second page, then second set of layers. My code is printing a header, then ALL of the pages and layers.

I have tried iterating through the array but am not sure where I need to put my nested loops. I have been trying different placement of my for loops and print statements. The closest I get is the header and all of the layers printed below it.

```
var theCount = 0;
for (var z = 0; z < isolatedPages.length; z++) {
    if (theCount != isolatedPages.length) {
        theCount++;
        console.println("header bookmark loop V" + theCount);
        for (var i = 0; i < hypertextArray.length; i++) {
            var layerNamesArray = hypertextArray[i];
            for (var x = 0; x < layerNamesArray.length; x++) {
                if (layerNamesArray.length > 1) {
                    console.println("layerNamesArray[" + i + "][" + x + "] = " + layerNamesArray[x]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output from the console for the current code:

```
header bookmark loop V1
layerNamesArray[1][0] = V1 - 347 (Dk Green)
layerNamesArray[1][1] = V1 - 346 (Med Green)
layerNamesArray[1][2] = V1 - 258 (Dk Purple)
layerNamesArray[3][0] = V2 - 346 (Med Green)
layerNamesArray[3][1] = V2 - 258 (Dk Purple)
layerNamesArray[3][2] = V2 - 190 (Dk Pink)
layerNamesArray[3][3] = V2 - 021 (Orange)
layerNamesArray[3][4] = V2 - 305 (Lt Blue)
header bookmark loop V2
layerNamesArray[1][0] = V1 - 347 (Dk Green)
layerNamesArray[1][1] = V1 - 346 (Med Green)
layerNamesArray[1][2] = V1 - 258 (Dk Purple)
layerNamesArray[3][0] = V2 - 346 (Med Green)
layerNamesArray[3][1] = V2 - 258 (Dk Purple)
layerNamesArray[3][2] = V2 - 190 (Dk Pink)
layerNamesArray[3][3] = V2 - 021 (Orange)
layerNamesArray[3][4] = V2 - 305 (Lt Blue)
```

Here is what I am wanting:

```
header bookmark loop V1
layerNamesArray[1][0] = V1 - 347 (Dk Green)
layerNamesArray[1][1] = V1 - 346 (Med Green)
layerNamesArray[1][2] = V1 - 258 (Dk Purple)
header bookmark loop V2
layerNamesArray[3][0] = V2 - 346 (Med Green)
layerNamesArray[3][1] = V2 - 258 (Dk Purple)
layerNamesArray[3][2] = V2 - 190 (Dk Pink)
layerNamesArray[3][3] = V2 - 021 (Orange)
layerNamesArray[3][4] = V2 - 305 (Lt Blue)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add in an example of the original data? I'm guessing it's something like `layerNamesArray = [[1, ["foo", "bar", "baz"], [2, ["bar", "baz"]]`, but it isn't very clear. Also, is there a reason why the data is formatted like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < hypertextArray.length; i++) {
    console.log("header bookmark loop V" + i);
            var layerNamesArray = hypertextArray[i];
            for (var x = 0; x < layerNamesArray.length; x++) {
                if (layerNamesArray.length > 1) {
                    console.println("layerNamesArray[" + i + "][" + x + "] = " + layerNamesArray[x]);
                }
            }
        }
```

And remove the outer first loop.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop should not be there.

Instead, print the header inside the loop on `hyperTextArray`.
Also make the loop counter increment in steps of two, since apparently you store page numbers at even indexes and layer arrays at odd indexes.

The inner `if` is useless, since the `for` will only iterate when that `if` condition is true.

You output the text "layerNamesArray[ ][ ]", but actually it should be "hypertextArray[ ][ ]" to be consistent.

So the corrected code would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < hypertextArray.length; i+=2) {
    console.println("header bookmark loop V" + hypertextArray[i]);
    var layerNamesArray = hypertextArray[i+1];
    for (var x = 0; x < layerNamesArray.length; x++) {
        console.println("hypertextArray["+i+"]["+x+"] = "+layerNamesArray[x]);
    }
}
```

In a bit more modern coding (if supported on the platform you use), it would be:

```
for (let i = 0; i < hypertextArray.length; i+=2) {
    console.println(`header bookmark loop V${hypertextArray[i]}`);
    for (const layer of hypertextArray[i+1]) {
        console.println(`hypertextArray[${i}][${x}] = ${layer}`);
    }
}
```

Or, you could loop one by one, and detect whether the item is an array:

```
for (const hypertextElem of hypertextArray) {
    if (Array.isArray(hypertextElem)) {
        for (const layer of hypertextElem) {
            console.println(`hypertextArray[${i}][${x}] = ${layer}`);
        }
    } else {
        console.println(`header bookmark loop V${hypertextElem}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some more background information. I am using Javascript within a PDF and Adobe Acrobat DC Pro. The console.println is to print to the Adobe console.
```
for (var z = 0; z < isolatedPages.length; z++) {
```
The outer loop is there because I had to filter down the pages within Acrobat. The test document I am using has 6 pages. It just so happens that the pages I am feeding to the isolatedPages are odd numbers. This will not always be the case. Sorry. I am new to posting here and not sure how much is too much to post. Thank you for the input/feedback.